# Display on Modal "Loading Animations" when sorting data of Table in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sorting

I create HTML Table, in which the data is fetch from MySQL Table in PHP, now i apply sorting option on it, and the database is huge, so when i click to sort. it take time, so i want that till completing sorting it show me loading animation, how?

**SORTING BUTTON**

```
 <tr>
    <th>VILLAGE<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sortTable(0)" style="cursor:pointer; float:right;" title="Sort by Alphabetical"></i></th>
    <th>Total Participant</th>
    <th>FORM NUMBER</th>
    <th>SUBMIT DATE<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sortTable(3)" style="cursor:pointer; float:right;" title="Sort by Time"</i></th>
    <th>EDIT</th>
    <th>DELETE</th>
  </tr>
```

**TABLE WITH DATA**

```
    <?php
include("connection.php");
$query ="SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.id) AS total_participants
  FROM general AS a 
  LEFT JOIN participant AS b ON a.id = b.gid
  GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.village ASC";
$run =mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $id=$row['0'];
    $createdate=$row[1];
    $createday=$row[2];
    $partnername=$row[3];
    $district=$row[4];
    $unioncouncil=$row[5];
    $village=$row[6];
    $vannumber=$row[7];
    $facilitator=$row[8];
    $beneficiarytype=$row[9];
    $rmultimedia=$row[10];
    $rgame=$row[11];
    $rsprort=$row[12];
    $rart=$row[13];
    $rgroupreading=$row[14];
    $rother=$row[15];
    $alandminer=$row[16];
    $apersonalsafety=$row[17];
    $abirthregister=$row[18];
    $aother=$row[19];
    $tstickstone=$row[20];
    $tohthers=$row[21];
    $sbirthregister=$row[22];
    $sother=$row[23];
    $formnumber=$row[24];
    $submitdatatime=$row[25];
  $totalParticipants = $row['total_participants'];
?>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $village; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $totalParticipants; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $formnumber; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $submitdatatime; ?></td>
      <td><a href='edit-general.php?edit_general=<?php echo $id; ?>'>Edit</td>
      <td><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)">Delete</a></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>

<?php } ?>
  </table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE FOR SORTING**

```
  <script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should tell us what you tried, it doesn't look to be an hard question so it could be interesting if you talked about your attempts.

Anyways, place your loading animation where you want:

```
<div id="loading-animation">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

And set `display:none` as css to *#loading-animation* element.

Then display this div according to *sorttable* function:

```
function sortTable(n) {
  document.getElementById('loading-animation').style.display='block';
  ...
  ...
  document.getElementById('loading-animation').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this address:
https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

view the source of one of them, then add one of them (or any loading spinner animation out there) to your CSS file.

for example, check this code snippet:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var showBtn = document.getElementById("showLoading");
var hideBtn = document.getElementById("hideLoading");

showBtn.onclick = function() {
  table.className += " loading";
};

hideBtn.onclick = function() {
  table.className = table.className.replace(" loading", "");
};
```

```css
.table-style {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:  20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-style thead tr th,
.table-style tbody tr td { padding: 10px; }
.table-style thead tr th { background: #ddd; }

.table-style tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #eee;
}

/* LOADER: START */
.loading { position: relative; }
.loading:before,
.loading:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
.loading:before { background: #ccc; }
.loading:after {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  border-top: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-right: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-left: 1.1em solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
  animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* LOADER: END  */
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table-style">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1-1</td>
    <td>Data 1-2</td>
    <td>Data 1-3</td>
    <td>Data 1-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 2-1</td>
    <td>Data 2-2</td>
    <td>Data 2-3</td>
    <td>Data 2-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 3-1</td>
    <td>Data 3-2</td>
    <td>Data 3-3</td>
    <td>Data 3-4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="showLoading">Show Loading</button>
<button id="hideLoading">Hide Loading</button>
```

Comment: If your table has already a class, you shoud write the JS part this way:

**1. First line: ** `table.className += " loading";`

**2. Last line** `table.className = table.className.replace(" loading", "");`

Comment: I edited my answer in order to add a solution for the already designed tables.

Comment: and showing the error... and the existing table id name is id="myTable"

Comment: yes, now it is not showing error... but it also can't display loading animation, why?

Comment: I just added a code snipet to check it out in action. Run it and check the code, hope it helps